# Removing Indices from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to get an output such as this:

```
169.764569892,  572870.0,  19.6976
```

However I have a problem because the files that I am inputing have a format similar to the output I just showed, but some line in the data have 'nan' as a variable which I need to remove.
I am trying to use this to do so:

```
TData_Pre_Out = map(itemgetter(0, 7, 8), HDU_DATA) 
TData_Pre_Filter = [Data for Data in TData_Pre_Out if Data != 'nan']
```

Here I am trying to use list comprehension to get the 'nan' to go away,  but the output still displays it, any help on properly filtering this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The improper output looks like this:

```
169.519361471,  nan,  nan
```

instead of what I showed above. Also, some more info:1) This is coming from a special data file, not a text file, so splitting lines wont work. 2) The input is exactly the same as the output, just mapped using the map() line that I show above and split into the indices I actually need (i.e. instead of using all of a data list like L = [(1,2,3),(3,4,5)] I only pull 1 and 3 from that list, to give you the gist of the data structure)
The Data is read in as so:

```
with pyfits.open(allfiles) as HDU:
HDU_DATA = HDU[1].data
```

The syntax is from a specialized program but you get the idea

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a line?

Comment: This one gives you the desired output: `print("169.764569892,  572870.0,  19.6976")`.

Comment: Sure I will add it to an edit, also why the downvote??

Comment: It's great that you have a sample bad ouput in your post, but please show a sample line from the file

Comment: Edited to address all concerns so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TData_Pre_Out = map(itemgetter(0, 7, 8), HDU_DATA)
```

This statement gives you **a list of tuples**. And then you compare the tuple with a string. All the `!=` comparisions success.

Answer (score 1):

Without showing how you read in your data, the solution can only be guessed.

However, if `HDU_DATA` stores real `NaN` values, try following:

Comparing variable to `NaN`s does not work with the equality operator `==`:

```
foo == nan
```

where `nan` and foo are both `NaN`s gives always false.

Use `math.isnan()` instead:

```
import math
...if math.isnan(Data)…
```

Comment: If he's reading it from a file, wouldn't he be getting a string then?

Comment: if `'nan'` is in the text file, it won't be a `NaN` object; it'll be the actual string. So this check won't really work, unless you want to throw in an `ast.literal_eval` or so

Comment: ^ Exactly my point. And the OP doesn't do `literal_eval` so they should be in strings.

Comment: Sure, if it's stored as `nan` and is not converted by whatever read-ins, it's a string and should work with `!='nan'`.

Comment: I don't see any code where he reads in the data, so we're all just guessing ;-)

Comment: Just saying, once it is mapped I believe it converts to a string and 'nan' would be a string regardless wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your description, this could work

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        vals = line.strip().split(',')
        print[v for v in vals if v!='nan']
```